audio prematurely stops on desktops, laptops and phones
I am building a website for a religious institution. I am using WordPress and Elementor.
the usual
<audio preload=metadata control>
<source src="path/to/audio/file.mp3" type="mpeg">
</audio>

Works perfectly on Desktops and Laptops but not on mobile phones.
After some research I reached this solution that will make the sound work on all devices:
<style>
  details {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 15px 0;
  }
  summary {
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: left; /* Align summary text to the left */
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease, transform 0.2s ease;
  }
  summary:hover {
    background-color: #e2e6ea;
    transform: scale(1.02);
  }
  summary small {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #6c757d;
  }
  #reveal {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #f1f3f5;
    text-align: left; /* Ensure the content inside the div is left-aligned */
  }
  p {
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin: 0;
    color: #495057;
    text-align: left; /* Align the paragraph text to the left */
  }
</style>

<details>
  <summary>
    Question 4: What is Tawheed?<br><small>(click to reveal or hide)</small>
  </summary>
  <div id="reveal">
    <p>Answer:<br>
      Tawheed, or monotheism, is Islam's foundational belief emphasizing Allah's oneness. It asserts that Allah is unique, incomparable, and has no partners, equals, or associates.
    </p>
  </div>
</details>

<style>
  .audio-player04 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  .play-button04 {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: #007BFF;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .play-button04:disabled {
    background-color: #cccccc;
  }
</style>
  
<div class="audio-player04">
  <button class="play-button04" id="playPause04" disabled>Click to Listen</button>
</div>
<audio id="audio04" preload="metadata">
  <source src="/audio/aqeeda_q04.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<script>
  const audio04 = document.getElementById('audio04');
  const playPauseButton04 = document.getElementById('playPause04');

  // When metadata is loaded, enable the play button
  audio04.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    playPauseButton04.disabled = false;
    playPauseButton04.textContent = 'Click to Listen';
  });

  // Play/pause button functionality
  playPauseButton04.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (audio04.paused) {
      audio04.play();
      playPauseButton04.textContent = 'Pause';
    } else {
      audio04.pause();
      playPauseButton04.textContent = 'Play';
    }
  });
  
  // Change button text to "Listen again" when audio ends
  audio04.addEventListener('ended', () => {
    playPauseButton04.textContent = 'Listen Again';
  });

  // Handle errors (e.g., file not found)
  audio04.addEventListener('error', () => {
    playPauseButton04.textContent = 'Error Loading File';
    playPauseButton04.disabled = true;
  });
</script>

The audio plays but it stops prematurely at different location/duration time.
The code above I copied and edited from some AI platforms. I don't understand the addEventListener part.
I also tried different audio file formats (mp3, mp4, m4a, wav, ogg). preload="auto". Among other simple alterations.
What makes the audio stop playing prematurely?
